# How to insert image to BasicTextField() in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm making a simply chat app, and I want to insert smiley to `BasicTextField()`, but I found that there's no property likes `inlineContent` in Text() here althought I can set TextFieldValue to annotatedString.

My code is almost identical to the [`UserInput()`](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetchat/app/src/main/java/com/example/compose/jetchat/conversation/UserInput.kt) in Jetchat (Jetpack Compose's official demo), except that the `EmojiTable` is replaced with the use of `inlineContent` to display my own smiley (I had saved all smileys' drawable before entering the page and can get them anywhere).

I don't want to use text instead of smiley. What should I do?

Comment: Although you can not directly insert an image into a textfield, you can create such an illusion to the users using a combination of `FlowRow`, `BasicTextField`, and your image (e.g., `Image`). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893037/chips-in-inputfield-like-gmail-in-jetpack-compose) for inspiration. However, instead of one textfield and a list of chips, you'll have to parse your text somehow (e.g., using Markdown) to determine if you should now show an `Image` or a `BasicTextField`.