# Chips in InputField like Gmail in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, input-field

I was wondering if it is possible in Jetpack Compose to get a Gmail like behavior,
anyone did something like this before and want to share their solution?

I just want to give the user the opportunity to add tags to their content before uploading, I don't need those pop-up suggestions like in the gif below.

Just simple chips in a `InputField`.

[image]

Comment: To answer your question. Yes its possible here is a clip of my implementation. I used the latest jetpack compose to build this editable chips component https://streamable.com/3et0pg

Comment: @RenzCarlo Oh wow, this is exactly how I want it to be.
Do you mind sharing your code and helping me and other developers out? There are no resources yet on how to implement such editable chips in compose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how I did it. Basically I just used flow row along with a text field

```
KoohaHashTagEditor(
    textFieldValue = hashTagTextValue,
    onValueChanged = {
        hashTagError = null
        val values = FormUtil.splitPerSpaceOrNewLine(it.text)

        if (values.size >= 2) {
            if (!FormUtil.isFilled(values[0])) {
                hashTagError = "At least 2 characters per tag."
            } else if (!FormUtil.checkTagMinimumCharacter(values[0])) {
                hashTagError = "At least 2 characters per tag."
            } else if (!FormUtil.checkTagMaximumCharacter(values[0])) {
                hashTagError = "Up to 50 characters per tag."
            }

            if (hashTagError == null) {
                addHashTag(values[0])
                hashTagTextValue = hashTagTextValue.copy(text = "")
            }
        } else {
            hashTagTextValue = it
        }
    },
    focusRequester = hashTagFocusRequester,
    focusedFlow = hashTagFocusedFlow.value,
    textFieldInteraction = hashTagInteraction,
    label = null,
    placeholder = "To add a tag, hit the enter or space bar on your keypad after each tag.",
    rowInteraction = rowInteraction,
    errorMessage = hashTagError,
    listOfChips = uiState.hashtags,
    modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
        if (it.key.keyCode == Key.Backspace.keyCode) {
            removeLastTag()
        }
        false
    },
    onChipClick = { chipIndex ->
        removeTagOnIndex(chipIndex)
    }
)
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun KoohaHashTagEditor(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue,
    onValueChanged: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
    focusedFlow: Boolean,
    textFieldInteraction: MutableInteractionSource,
    label: String?,
    placeholder: String,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    message: String? = null,
    errorMessage: String? = null,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
        keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
        imeAction = ImeAction.Default
    ),
    rowInteraction: MutableInteractionSource,
    listOfChips: List<String> = emptyList(),
    onChipClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    val isLight = MaterialTheme.colors.isLight

    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val keyboardManager = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(
                vertical = 10.dp,
                horizontal = 20.dp
            )
            .clickable(
                indication = null,
                interactionSource = rowInteraction,
                onClick = {
                    focusRequester.requestFocus()
                    keyboardManager?.show()
                }
            )
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {

                if (label != null) {
                    Text(
                        text = "$label:",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                            color = if (focusedFlow) MaterialTheme.colors.secondary else if (isLight) Color.Gray else Color.White
                        )
                    )
                }

                TextFieldContent(
                    textFieldValue = textFieldValue,
                    placeholder = placeholder,
                    onValueChanged = onValueChanged,
                    focusRequester = focusRequester,
                    textFieldInteraction = textFieldInteraction,
                    readOnly = readOnly,
                    keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
                    focusManager = focusManager,
                    listOfChips = listOfChips,
                    modifier = modifier,
                    emphasizePlaceHolder = false,
                    onChipClick = onChipClick
                )
            }

            ErrorSection(
                message = message,
                errorMessage = errorMessage
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun TextFieldContent(
    textFieldValue: TextFieldValue,
    placeholder: String,
    onValueChanged: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit,
    focusRequester: FocusRequester,
    textFieldInteraction: MutableInteractionSource,
    readOnly: Boolean,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions,
    focusManager: FocusManager,
    listOfChips: List<String>,
    emphasizePlaceHolder: Boolean = false,
    modifier: Modifier,
    onChipClick: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    Box {
        val isFocused = textFieldInteraction.collectIsFocusedAsState()

        if (textFieldValue.text.isEmpty() && listOfChips.isEmpty()) {
            Text(
                text = placeholder,
                color = if (emphasizePlaceHolder && !isFocused.value) {
                    MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface
                } else {
                    if (MaterialTheme.colors.isLight) {
                        LocalCustomColors.current.muted
                    } else {
                        Color.Gray
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.CenterStart)
            )
        }

        FlowRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            mainAxisSpacing = 5.dp
        ) {

            repeat(times = listOfChips.size) { index ->
                Chip(
                    onClick = { onChipClick(index) },
                    modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
                    trailingIcon = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .clip(CircleShape)
                                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
                                .padding(3.dp)
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.Close),
                                contentDescription = null,
                                modifier = Modifier.size(12.dp),
                                tint = if (MaterialTheme.colors.isLight) {
                                    Color.White
                                } else {
                                    Color.Black
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    colors = ChipDefaults
                        .chipColors(
                            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
                            contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onSecondary
                        )
                ) {
                    Text(text = listOfChips[index])
                }
            }

            BasicTextField(
                value = textFieldValue,
                onValueChange = onValueChanged,
                modifier = modifier
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .width(IntrinsicSize.Min),
                singleLine = false,
                textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface),
                decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .wrapContentWidth()
                            .defaultMinSize(minHeight = 48.dp),
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start
                    ) {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                        ) {
                            Row(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .defaultMinSize(minWidth = 4.dp)
                                    .wrapContentWidth(),
                            ) {
                                innerTextField()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                interactionSource = textFieldInteraction,
                cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary),
                readOnly = readOnly,
                keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = {
                        focusManager.clearFocus()
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ErrorSection(
    message: String?,
    errorMessage: String?
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .wrapContentHeight()
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
        ) {

            if (message != null) {
                val color = if (MaterialTheme.colors.isLight) {
                    Color.Gray
                } else {
                    Color.White
                }
                Text(
                    text = message,
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(color = color)
                )
            }
            if (errorMessage != null) {
                Chip(
                    onClick = {
                    },
                    colors = ChipDefaults
                        .chipColors(
                            backgroundColor = Color.Red,
                            contentColor = Color.White
                        ),
                    leadingIcon = {
                        Icon(
                            painter = rememberVectorPainter(image = Icons.Default.Info),
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = errorMessage,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(fontSize = 12.sp),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, could you please also provide the remember variables like hashTagTextValue, hashTagInteraction etc. And the FormUtil class?

Comment: I think the sample i gave is already enough to understand how to implement such component feel free to tick the answer button if I answer your question thank you

Comment: Yes it is working, thank you very much.
Little hard to fill in the missing things but for people who not beginners in jetpack compose this is a really helpful answer.

Comment: @RenzCarlo could you please fill out this because I cannot figure out how to do it? Or share some repository you have this on?

Comment: @RenzCarlo Please provide repository link.