# is it possible to insert some tags in TextField compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing with compose. And I want to insert some tags in TextFiled(EditText)
I searched for buildAnnotatedString.
However it looks like possible only for textStyle.
In Text widget, it is possible to insert icon with buildAnnotatedString, But in TextField, I can't insert inlineContent So that can't insert some Composable.
What I want to looks like below image

[image]

is it possible in Compose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71893037/chips-in-inputfield-like-gmail-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: thank you for your answer. But the sample is like flowLayout. What I want is to insert tag between letters.